# Global text caret position in Linux

Tags: python, linux, x11

I need to find global caret position in Linux. The problem is similar to [this one for Windows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application/). Do you guys have any idea?

More information: 
 I am trying to make input method for a certain Indic language. I am using IBus libraries in Python. I need to create something like the lookup table found in IBus but my requirements are such that I decided its better if I make the whole thing again using tk (or something). The link in the question solves this problem for windows where a tooltip follows the text caret. So I need something just like that but for X-Windows.

Comment: can you please give more information?

Comment: Okay. I am trying to make input method for a certain indic language. I am using IBus libraries in Python. I need to create something like the lookup table found in IBus but my requirements are such that I decided its better if I make the whole thing again using tk (or something). The link in the question solves this problem for windows where a tooltip follows the text caret. So I need something just like that but for X-Windows.

Comment: put that in the question, please...

Comment: I am not a downvoter, but I would imagine it might be because you are presupposing that the X11 architecture adheres to whatever assumptions you are trying to carry over from the Windows world, and/or because you are making people who are unfamiliar with Windows read and attempt to understand a technical article about Windows which does not make much sense to somebody with only X11 background (and/or it discusses features of Windows which are particularly repulsive; I don't know).

Comment: Also, reverting to bare X11 hacking (in tk, no less!) rather than try to address any shortcomings in IBus sounds like the wrong approach entirely.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a caret position in X11. While the older UIM framework did a fairly good job of displaying the input method UI near the cursor position, this failed often enough that it was abandoned.

You might want to take a look at the [SCIM](http://www.scim-im.org/) framework. Note that it is usually preferred to hint the application at the completion state rather than provide a separate editor, as this gives a more seamless integration.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! All I had to do was create a method in my IBus engine class (sub class of IBus.Engine) called do_set_cursor_location which handles the signals created when position of the caret changes. Here is more from IBus manual:  [The "set-cursor-location" signal](http://ibus.googlecode.com/svn/docs/ibus-1.5/IBusEngine.html#IBusEngine-set-cursor-location).

That means the problem is solved for now, although I certainly don't know what is happening under the hood.

Thanks guys.